# Is it safe to change the data source format to OLE DB database file when using a htm/html as the datasource to remove the limitation of 62 fields?

Tags: ms-word, field, mailmerge

I have a mail merge datasource which is in htm/html format and it contains 70 fields. Since there is a limitation of 62 fields for such datasources([Reference](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/mail-merge-maximum-number-of-fields-2013/68c81d26-f4cb-42fd-9bc9-1a087b7b1dbd)).
Is it safe to change the datasource type to OLE DB database file in the confirm datasource dialog when selecting the datasource?

[image]

Comment: Cross-posted at: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/mail-merge-field-limit-for-html-data-sources/01f9999d-2375-466b-8a05-318de2898add. For cross-posting etiquette, please read: http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you choose the "All web pages" type (and this is the default type in the case of an HTML file), you are in essence choosing a *Word internal file converter* to retrieve your data. The reason you end up with the concatenated columns is because

1. The internal converter is not primarily designed to "read data sources". It's there to convert a document in HTML format into a document in Word format.
2. Your HTML file contains a table in HTML format, so naturally, the converter tries to convert that into a Word table
3. However, Word tables can only have 63 columns, whereas HTML tables can have more, so the converter has to deal with that somehow. In this case, it concatenates the column data so column 63 ends up containing all the remaining data in the row.
4. Once the document is converted, Word uses the converted document as the data source. It's really no different from the situation where it uses a Word document as the data source.

If your HTML file actually contained (say) 1 paragraph of 70 comma-delimited values for each row of data, rather than an HTML table row with td cells, Word would end up treating the data as 70 separate columns (but it would also probably ask for the column delimiter every time you used the file, and you would have to ensure that commas in the data were correctly quoted.

In general, when you choose the "OLE DB Database Files" option, Word either knows of an OLE DB Provider type that can read the specified type of file, or it won't be able to read the file. In this case, what it tries to do is read the file using the Jet OLE DB provider (or in recent versions of Word, the ACE OLE DB provider).

The Jet/ACE providers are one of the mechanisms used to read Access .mdb/.accdb data, but these providers can read a number of formats such as Excel workbook data and plain text file data, using a number of what Jet/ACE calls "Installable ISAMs (IISAMs).

Since there is an IISAM for HTML format data, Word will try to get the data using that IISAM.

In that case, as long as the IISAM can actually read the HTML (it may not be able to read more modern versions of HTML very well) it works much more like the case where Word gets data from Excel. For example, if your HTML file contained two tables, you may get to choose which table to read, cf. an Excel workbook with multiple worksheets and perhaps named ranges.

Jet/ACE IISAMs generally do not support more than 255 columns. 70 shhould be fine. However, you may need to verify what the HTML IISAM does about

1. Columns with mixed data types (for example where some rows have numbers in them and others have text). When the Excel IISAM finds such data in the first 8 rows (by default) it tries to choose a format - somtimes that can mean that cells with text are read as if they contained "0". FWIW I do not think the HTML IISAM does that, but I would check anyway.
2. Columns with large amount of text, particularly if there is more than one such column. The IISAM is quite likely to truncate such columns to 255 characters or even less.
3. Columns with non-ANSI data (non-ANSI Unicode text e.g. Arabic, Hindi or Chinese text.

Other than delimited text files which will let you go over theat 255 limit if they are read by the internal converter, the only data source I know that will let WOrd see *thousands* of columns is SQL Server. Other servers with OLE DB providers such as MySQL might allow that too. If you have to use a very large number of columns, be aware that you may not see all the available field names in the relevant dropdowns in WOrd, but you should be able to insert the MERGEFIELD codes in manually in the usual way.

Answer (score 1):

What is your current mailmerge connection method (OLEDB, DDE)? By switching to the OLEDB connection method - which is Word's default - you would not be changing the datasource type (only the connection method). Whether doing so will work with your datasource can easily be established by changing to OLEDB and leaving the datasource type alone. If it doesn't work, close the document without saving (or revert to the current connection method.

Regardless, the screen you're showing allows you to specify a datasource *type*, not the connection method. HTML files are not OLE DB database files and you'd be unlikely to find your datasource if you switched to that file type.

In any event, the 62-field limitation most likely only relates to the fields you can see via the GUI. If you know the field name, you can insert its reference via the keyboard. To do so, simply press Ctrl-F9 to create a pair of field braces (i.e. { }) and fill in between them with 'MERGEFIELD' and the field name, thus { MERGEFIELD FieldName }.

Comment: I didn't implicitly give a connection method and as I understand from your comment, the default is OLEDB.
As for your second point if I select any of the options 2 or 3 the fields starting from field number 62 will be combined into 1 field which is an issue(ex: Field62Field63Field64Field65Field66Field67Field68Field69Field70). If I select the 1st option then it would work fine. My understanding was that it would convert the given datasource to which ever type we select from the list. Is this an incorrect assumption?

Comment: Specifying a particular datasource type doesn't convert an existing datasource to that type. You should be able to use a field coded as { MERGEFIELD Field63 }, for example. I suspect that all you've done is insert the mergefield «Field1» and tried to overtype the 1 with 63. That won't work.

Comment: When I tried the suggested method I got an error: Invalid Merge field
This merge field is used in the main document, but it does not exists in the data source.

Comment: In which case you need to check what the field's name is in the datasource. The name in the document has to match that - unless the field is unnamed, in which case it might respond to a name like C63, F63, or M63.

Comment: I rechecked the field name. If I add some data to those fields the data would also get combined.
When I insert the combined field in the document, it shows as this(Don't mind the number difference from the other comments) «Field6Field7Field8Field9» :(
When I tried { MERGEFIELD Field6 } it's giving me the invalid merge field error

Comment: Is there any document specifying the field limit of each datasource format?
So that I could change the datasource format to a supported type and feed the data through that

Comment: I am not aware of what limit might apply to html datasources. Excel datasources support up to 255 fields and CSV datasources support even more.